# GitHub Action failed due to workflow is not valid

Tags: php, laravel, github, github-actions, cicd

I am trying to upload my laravel application on shared hosting for auto-deployment. I have integrated the GitHub CI/CD feature with my ftp server. I want to exclude the specific files and folders when github deploys code on FTP server. So for this, I have written then main.yml file. When I push the code on repositories I always get the following error:

```
The workflow is not valid. .github/workflows/main.yml (Line: 23, Col: 11): A sequence was not expected
```

But when I remove the exclude option from main.yml file then it work fine but I want to exclude some files and folders.

main.yml

```
on:
    push:
      branches:
        - staging
name:  Deploy website on push
jobs:
  web-deploy:
    name:  Deploy
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    timeout-minutes: 5 # time out after 15 minutes (default is 360 minutes)
    steps:
    - name:  Get latest code
      uses: actions/checkout@v3
    
    - name:  Sync files
      uses: SamKirkland/FTP-Deploy-Action@4.3.3
      with:
        server: ${{ secrets.ftp_server }}
        username: ${{ secrets.ftp_username }}
        password: ${{ secrets.ftp_password }}
        server-dir: /public_html/admin-test-com/
        exclude:
          - public/**
          - vendor/**
          - crons/**
          - storage/**
          - .github
          - .github/**
          - .env
          - composer.json
          - composer.lock
          - .htaccess
```

I don't know that what is the issue with this file.
Is there any other way that I only upload the changed files instead of all files?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Github inputs cannot be arrays, and please refer to the [action's documentation](https://github.com/SamKirkland/FTP-Deploy-Action#exclude-files), what you want to do is:

```
- name:  Sync files
  uses: SamKirkland/FTP-Deploy-Action@4.3.3
  with:
    server: ${{ secrets.ftp_server }}
    username: ${{ secrets.ftp_username }}
    password: ${{ secrets.ftp_password }}
    server-dir: /public_html/admin-test-com/
    exclude: |
      public/**
      vendor/**
      crons/**
      storage/**
      .github
      .github/**
      .env
      composer.json
      composer.lock
      .htaccess
```

Comment: May also add [linter](https://rhysd.github.io/actionlint/#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) link.